# Splitting a text file into multiple files by specific character sequence

Tags: java, text, split, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I have a file with the following format.

```
.I 1
.T
experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a
wing in a slipstream . 1989
.A
brenckman,m.
.B
experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a
wing in a slipstream .
.I 2
.T
simple shear flow past a flat plate in an incompressible fluid of small
viscosity .
.A
ting-yili
.B
some texts...
some more text....
.I 3
...
```

"***.I 1***" indicate the beginning of chunk of text corresponding to ***doc ID1*** and "***.I 2***" indicates the beginning of chunk of text corresponding to ***doc ID2***.

**what I need** is read the text between ".I 1" and ".I 2" and save it as a separate file like "DOC_ID_1.txt" and then read the text between ".I 2" and ".I 3"
and save it as a separate file like "DOC_ID_2.txt" and so on. *lets assume that the number of .I # is not known.*

I have tried this but cannot finish it. any help will be appreciated

```
String inputDocFile="C:\\Dropbox\\Data\\cran.all.1400";     
try {
     File inputFile = new File(inputDocFile);
     FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
     String line=null;
     String outputDocFileSeperatedByID="DOC_ID_";
     //Pattern docHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile(".I ", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
     ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<> ();
     int docID =0;
     try {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          line = bufferedReader.readLine();
          while (line != null) {
              if (line.startsWith(".I"))
              { 
                 result.add(new ArrayList<String>());
                 result.get(docID).add(".I");
                 line = bufferedReader.readLine();

                 while(line != null && !line.startsWith(".I")){
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    }
                     ++docID;
              }        
              else line = bufferedReader.readLine();
          }

      } finally {
          bufferedReader.close();
      }
   } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(ReadFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```

Comment: Note : you are using the old fashioned way to read a file line by line. Today, `Files.lines()` gives you a `Stream<String>`. Then, a regex will help you to find the `I \d`. Finally, use `Files.write()` in order to easily write to the appropriate file.

Comment: Arnaud Denoyelle thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the lines which match "I n".

The regex you need is : `^.I \d$`

- `^` indicates the beginning of the line. Hence, if there are some whitespaces or text before `I`, the line will not match the regex.
- `\d` indicates any digit. For the sake of simplicty, I allow only one digit in this regex.
- `$` indicates the end of the line. Hence, if there are some characters after the digit, the line will not match the expression.

Now, you need to read the file line by line and keep a reference to the file in which you write the current line.

Reading a file line by line is much easier in Java 8 with `Files.lines();`

```
private String currentFile = "root.txt";

public static final String REGEX = "^.I \\d$";

public void foo() throws Exception{

  Path path = Paths.get("path/to/your/input/file.txt");
  Files.lines(path).forEach(line -> {
    if(line.matches(REGEX)) {
      //Extract the digit and update currentFile
      currentFile = "File DOC_ID_"+line.substring(3, line.length())+".txt";
      System.out.println("Current file is now : currentFile);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Writing this line to "+currentFile + " :" + line);
      //Files.write(...);
    }
  });
```

**Note** : In order to extract the digit, I use a raw `"".substring()` which I consider as evil but it is easier to understand. You can do it in a better way with a `Pattern` and a `Matcher`  :

With this regex : "`.I (\\d)`". (The same as before but with parenthesis which indicates what you will want to capture). Then :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".I (\\d)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(".I 3");
if(matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));//display "3"
}
```

Comment: a very better approach, i did this.

Comment: after using your suggestion when i tried to write the "line" into files it doesnot work properly and some of the files are empty and some have all the input file. 
this is the writing part that I added to your code:

Answer (score 1):

Look up regex, Java has inbuilt libraries for this.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

These links will give you a starting point, effectively you can use counter to perform a pattern match against the string and store anything between the first pattern match and the second pattern match. This information can be output to a separate file using the Formatter class.

Found here:-
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String inputFile="C:\\logs\\test.txt"; 
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(inputFile)));
         String line=null;
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         int count=1;
        try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                if(line.startsWith(".I")){
                    if(sb.length()!=0){
                        File file = new File("C:\\logs\\DOC_ID_"+count+".txt");
                        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
                        writer.println(sb.toString());
                        writer.close();
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                        count++;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                sb.append(line);
            }

           } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
           }
           finally {
                  br.close();

              }
    }

}
```